# How can show root url all product in single page?

Tags: category, category-products, product-page, magento1.9.3

I don't have advanced level magento code edit anyway I can do it.
My website need to add menu all product show link(link name: All Product).
All product added to mobiles.

Category tree are same like below

```
 - Mobiles (root category)
     - iphone(category)
        - iphone 11 (product)
        - iphone 9 (product)
     - samsung (category) 
        - galaxy 9 (product)
        - galay 11 (product)
```

This category page works fine that main reason

> catalog -> manage category -> iphone(category) select -> General
>   Information -> URL key

I can't find out Mobiles (root category) under URL key form.
How can I get same like url key in  Mobiles (root category). 
How can design all product show single page using with Mobiles (root category).

Comment: root category is not mean to be shown for users, create a subcategory and move your all products  there

Comment: Yes, Root category isn't show users. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create main category like **All Product under the root category Mobiles** and then assign all products to this category and set **Include in Menu to NO** so it will not show in top menu and then manually open link like 
**yourwebsite.com/all-products.html**
and it will show all products

Comment: Already found answer anyway thanks, It's correct but one problem I already added more than 200 product again manually add under All Product category

Comment: ok good to see your issue solved if my answer is ok then accept the answer